# Codes reappear after replacing ABS unit

Tags: toyota, abs, warning-light, 4runner, break

2001 toyota 4runner V6 3.4l 2wd SR5

ABS, brake & check eng warning lights are still on after replacing the ABS unit. What do I check next?

Comment: Have you reset the codes?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! And after you clear the codes (as GdD suggests), if any re-appear, what are the *exact* codes?

Comment: What has the 'check engine' warning light to do with ABS?

Comment: On my Ford several warning lights came up: engine, brakes, ABS, oil. The fault was with the instrument cluster itself.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Many people generically call any dash light as a CEL.